# plotting lat long on map

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have data arranges as table below. I want to plot the lat lon on a map with the names.

```
name      lat        lon
a       35.48     85.59
b       35.87     85.16
c       35.12     85.41
d       35.32     85.76
e       35.81     85.48 
f       35.25     85.17
g       35.66     85.40
```

I tried the below script but i am unable to carry out this work

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("input_latlon.csv")
print(df)
#fig = px.scatter_geo(df,lat='lat',lon='long', hover_name="id")
#fig.update_layout(title = 'World map', title_x=0.5)
#fig.show()
```

I hope experts may help me.

Comment: Can you provide an example image related to what you are looking for?

Comment: @Isr729 it is something like this https://datascientyst.com/plot-latitude-longitude-pandas-dataframe-python/

Comment: The code should work, what error are you getting?

Comment: ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['lon', 'name', 'lat']

Comment: Check your input csv file, the name might not be the same, also check if there is some space in the names. What does df.columns give you?

Comment: if possible plz provide a solution using example data provided

Comment: print `df.columns` and see what it gives

Comment: it prints whole data

Answer (score 0):

The data provided has the column names as **"lat"**, **"lon"**, and **"name"**. But, the map is expecting the unknown columns named as **"long"** and **"id"**. The unknown values are wrongly called in the `scatter_geo` function change the **"long"** --> **"lon"** and **"id"** --> **"name"** and it should work by that.

The below code is will run perfectly.

```
fig = px.scatter_geo(dataset, lat='lat', lon='lon', hover_name="name")
fig.update_layout(title = 'World map', title_x=0.5)
fig.show()
```